# Delete the first occurrence of an item in a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to delete the first occurrence of an item from a linked list using `list.first` and `list.next` only. (This is not using Java `LinkedList<E>`.)

I have written the following code, but it deletes all occurrences instead of just the first one:

```
private static <T> Cell<T> remove(T n,Cell<T> list)
{
   Cell<T> ptr;  // pointer
   Cell<T> temp=null; // new empty list
   for(ptr=list; ptr!=null; ptr=ptr.next) {
     if(!ptr.first.equals(n))
       temp=new Cell<T>(ptr.first,temp); //I guess this is the problem
   }
   if(ptr!=null)
     ptr=ptr.next;
   for(; temp!=null; temp=temp.next)
     ptr=new Cell<T>(temp.first,ptr);
   return ptr;
}
```

If `n` equals `3` and `list` equals `[1,3,4,5,3,2]`, the result I get is `[1,4,5,2]`, but I want it to be `[1,4,5,3,2]`.

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you store the first deletion in a bool variable "deletedYet"? do the if clause like this:  if(!ptr.first.equals(n) || deletedYet), set deletedYet initially to false, after you deleted an element for the firstTime set it to true?

Comment: You're traversing the whole list, checking each value and skipping the ones that match what you're searching, not taking into account whether it's the first match or not.

Comment: @outlyer do you have any idea of how to modify my current code. especially this line. `if(!ptr.first.equals(n)) temp = new Cell<T>(ptr.first,temp)`

Comment: Use Michael's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You may have an easier time modifying the original list, rather than creating a new one. You could simply keep a pointer to the head of the list and iterate through the list with a current and a previous pointer. When you find the first cell that contains n, rebind the previous cell's .next to skip over the current cell. That way, you can immediately return the head of the list without continuing to recurse.

Comment: yeah I have done that method - deleting from the current list. I am doing in this way just because I want to try a different approach tackling the same problem.